# How can I use response to a POST request in robot framework automate test

Tags: automated-tests, robotframework

I'm using POST request so I can login on some account("biker login") from a site in one of my tests. I want to use the response from that test in the next test( I want to use Authorization token that it gives me ) 
how can I do that ?

```
*** Test Cases ***
Biker Login
POST    https://somesite.somesite/auth/login     
   {"phoneNumber":"phoneNumber","password" : "password","versionCode": 100} headers={"Content-Type":"application/json"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Hit post request using some Header as in your question

   `HttpLibrary.HTTP . POST    https://somesite.somesite/auth/login`
2. Get Response using following keyword

   `${json}=    HttpLibrary.HTTP . Get Response Body`

   suppose now `${json}` has content like this

   `{json} = {
     "token_type":"bearer",
     "expires_in":3600,
     "refresh_token":"IwOGYzYTlmM2YxOTQ5MGE3YmNmMDFkNTVk",
     "scope":"create"
   }`
3. Now get token using its key `/refresh_token` and Set is as suite Variable

   `${somesiteCertificate}=    HttpLibrary.HTTP.Get Json Value ${json}    /refresh_token
   Set Suite Variable      ${somesiteCertificate}`

Suite variables are accessible in entire suite so that you can use it in any subsequent testcases for more details you can look at [HttpLibrary.HTTP](http://peritus.github.io/robotframework-httplibrary/HttpLibrary.html#Get%20Json%20Value)